# Exercism: clean and format a phone number in Clojure

Tags: programming-challenge, formatting, clojure, lisp

**Problem statement**

> Phone Number
>
> Write a program that cleans up user-entered phone numbers so that they can be sent SMS messages.
>
> The rules are as follows:
>
> 1. If the phone number is less than 10 digits assume that it is bad number
> 2. If the phone number is 10 digits assume that it is good
> 3. If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is 1, trim the 1 and use the last 10 digits
> 4. If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is not 1, then it is a bad number
> 5. If the phone number is more than 11 digits assume that it is a bad number

**Proposed Solution**

```
(ns phone-number
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(def non-digits #"\D")
(def parts #"^1?(...)(...)(....)$")
(def error-val ["000" "000" "0000"])

(defn- digits [n] (str/replace n non-digits ""))

(defn- trio-h [n]
  (if-let [ps (re-find parts n)]
    (rest ps)
    error-val))

(defn- trio [n] (-> n digits trio-h))

(defn number [n] (-> n trio str/join))

(defn area-code [n] (-> n trio first))

(defn pretty-print [n]
  (let [[area exch line] (trio n)]
    (format "(%s) %s-%s" area exch line)))
```

**Questions**

1. In `pretty-print` is the use of `let` necessary? Or is there a way in Clojure to splice in the result of `(trio n)` in-place for the call to `format`? The result of `(trio n)` is a vector containing three strings and the `format` call is expecting three `%s` strings to stick into the format string. If there is an alternative to my use of `let`, which is preferred?
2. Are the names ok? Do they read like Clojure names? Is there a convention for naming a one-off helper function?
3. Is it better to keep `trio-h` a separate helper function, or `let` it inside the using function, or would you just use the code in-place instead?
4. `:refer`ing `clojure.string/replace` triggers a warning (since it collides with `clojure.core/replace`) so I `:refer`ed all of `clojure.string`. Is there a way to `:refer` `as` to avoid the collision?
5. Do you have other improvements you could suggest?

**Tests**

See [the Exercism page for the Phone Number problem in Clojure](http://exercism.io/exercises/clojure/phone-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still learning clojure, but I'll contribute what I can.

1. I don't know if it is prefered or not, but if you wanted to get rid of the `let`, you could do something like `(apply (partial format "(%s) %s-%s") trio)` or `(apply format (concat '["(%s) %s-%s"] trio))` instead.
2. Naming seems ok.
3. No comment.
4. I don't know.
5. Your regex for `parts` is suboptimal.  `'.'` will pick up any character, but you really only want digits.  Something like `"^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$"` would be more accurate.

Comment: For 1, even simpler would be `(apply format "(%s) %s-%s" (trio n))`, but it might be better to just use a `let` for clarity's sake.